# How to change the naming structure of the dependent libraries in the zip produced by sbt-native-packager?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am using the Universal plugin of the sbt-native-packager to create a zip package. I am using the below setting for creating a default structure:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.1.4")

enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
```

Currently all my project dependencies in the zip fall under the lib folder e.g.

```
lib/
    ch.qos.logback.logback-classic-1.1.3.jar
    dom4j.dom4j-1.6.1.jar
```

How do I change the name of all the libraries to contain only the artifactId and version of the jar and not the complete name. For example, for the above, I want something like this:

```
lib/
    logback-classic-1.1.3.jar
    dom4j-1.6.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic for this is hard coded in the [JavaAppPackaging](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/JavaApp.scala#L98-L104) archetype. However you can remap your library dependencies.

```
mappings in Universal := (mappings in Universal).value.map {
  case (file, dest) if dest.startsWith("lib/") =>
        file -> changeDestination(dest)
  case mapping => mapping
}

def changeDestination(dest: String): String = ???
```

Next you need to change the `scriptClasspathOrdering` which is responsible for the `app_classpath` defined in the [BashStartScriptPlugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/scripts/BashStartScriptPlugin.scala#L176).

```
scriptClasspathOrdering := scriptClasspathOrdering.value.map {
   case (file, dest) if dest.startsWith("lib/") =>
         file -> changeDestination(dest)
   case mapping => mapping
}
```

The destination folder should be `lib/` as the bash script assumes this.

Note that I have not tested this as this is a very uncommon use case. However the main idea should be clear :)

cheers,
Muki